# vscode .net assembly error "The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

[image: added Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration in .csproj]

I am still getting a reference error in vscode:

> The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Extensions'

Comment: You have to install the nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/

Comment: @MarkusMeyer have tried with dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, also with nuget extension in vscode not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps solved this for me:

1. Deleted `bin` directory
2. Add packages
3. `dotnet restore -f`

Answer (score 0):

You must install Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration with .Net CLI in Vscode .

You can use below code :

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration --version 6.0.1
```

NOTE : In version you must use your current .NetFramework version

Nuget : [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/)

Comment: yes sir have done it "<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="6.0.0" />" in .csproj .netversion 6.0

Comment: its not working tho added package with cli and then also tried with nuget vscode extension

Comment: @Sumanth I use .Net CLI in my projects where I work with vs code, but anyway, thank you for the positive point you said.